# Convert Time to some Format

Tags: excel

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but please consider my question below.

Using formula in excel, how can I convert the date in `2012:06:28:15:52:32:000` format into 
something `6/28/2012 15:52`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is in A1 try this formula in B1

```
=TEXT(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",""),14)+0,"0000-00-00 00\:00\:00")+0
```

format B1 in required date/time format, i.e. m/d/yyyy hh:mm